# Clarification of the brightness of bioluminescent proteins

Tags: green-fluorescent-protein, optics

One basic thing I'm not too clear on, which I would like to be clear on, is the brightness per mass unit of GFP or luciferase.  I was having trouble finding a resource that would state the brightness at least for standard GFP or luciferase per gram, for example.  Is there a basic rule for the maximum brightness for either of them?  I'm aware this might end up being a vague question, but I could use help clarifying this.  I found brightness as a product of the extinction coefficient and quantum yield but I wasn't sure how to translate that to watts.

Comment: Search `quantum yield`

Comment: So I understand that the quantum yield is the ratio of photons emitted to photons absorbed, but I still don't know what's generally the maximum brightness of at least certain kinds of GFP under a sufficiently bright light source, if that question makes sense.